# CheckeListBox turn labels to invisible when the layer(checklistbox item) is unchecked

Tags: c#, visual-studio

its my first question here so im sorry for any mistakes.
Anyway, my question isn't about a code problem, its about the idea,
I got a checked list box where each item is a "Layer", and i got a picture box containing a picture of a map, my intention is that each layer will have labels which will be presented on the map descripting a place, for example: a map of a city, layer of Restaurants, and there will be on the map labels of "Macdonalds", and when ill uncheck that restaurant layer the labels visible will be false (lbl.visible = false) this is the main idea, and most of it ive already done and its working.

**The problem** is that i dont know how to "bind" the labels to the layer so that when ill uncheck it ill could turn the lables to invisible.

sry for any grammer or misspelling mistakes.

and ty for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, created a list of the items in the checkedlistbox and for each item list of labels, so List> will do it...

thought this issue will take more time to overcome...